# Error while integrating Dagger Hilt Android

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-hilt, native-android

After updating dagger hilt library unable to run the app. Attached source code for reference.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ayDegknQY37SGplXMc57UtDF4oJNM6XY/view?usp=sharing

[image]